# Keep radio button checked after page reload in PHP

Tags: php, radio-button

I'm trying to paginate the results of an api call in 10 pages(just like ebay or google does). I created 10 radio buttons to select the page that I want to display. My problem is that I cannot keep selected the radio button after clicking on it. To be more specific i did it like this:

```
$results .= "<FORM ACTION=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "\" METHOD=\"POST\"> \n";
        $results .= "<INPUT TYPE=\"radio\" NAME=\"pageNumber\" VALUE=\"1\" onchange=\"this.form.submit();\" check(".$_SESSION['PageNumber'].",1); >1";
        $results .= "<INPUT TYPE=\"radio\" NAME=\"pageNumber\" VALUE=\"2\" onchange=\"this.form.submit();\" check(".$_SESSION['PageNumber'].",2);>2";
        $results .= "<INPUT TYPE=\"radio\" NAME=\"pageNumber\" VALUE=\"3\" onchange=\"this.form.submit();\" check(".$_SESSION['PageNumber'].",3);>3";
        $results .= "<INPUT TYPE=\"radio\" NAME=\"pageNumber\" VALUE=\"4\" onchange=\"this.form.submit();\" check(".$_SESSION['PageNumber'].",4);>4";
        $results .= "<INPUT TYPE=\"radio\" NAME=\"pageNumber\" VALUE=\"5\" onchange=\"this.form.submit();\" check(".$_SESSION['PageNumber'].",5);>5";
        $results .= "<INPUT TYPE=\"radio\" NAME=\"pageNumber\" VALUE=\"6\" onchange=\"this.form.submit();\" check(".$_SESSION['PageNumber'].",6);>6";
        $results .= "<INPUT TYPE=\"radio\" NAME=\"pageNumber\" VALUE=\"7\" onchange=\"this.form.submit();\" check(".$_SESSION['PageNumber'].",7);>7";
        $results .= "<INPUT TYPE=\"radio\" NAME=\"pageNumber\" VALUE=\"8\" onchange=\"this.form.submit();\" check(".$_SESSION['PageNumber'].",8);>8";
        $results .= "<INPUT TYPE=\"radio\" NAME=\"pageNumber\" VALUE=\"9\" onchange=\"this.form.submit();\" check(".$_SESSION['PageNumber'].",9);>9";
        $results .= "<INPUT TYPE=\"radio\" NAME=\"pageNumber\" VALUE=\"10\" onchange=\"this.form.submit();\" check(".$_SESSION['PageNumber'].",10);>10";
        $results .= "</FORM> \n";
```

And I define the check function like this:

```
function check($opt , $value){
    if($opt==$value)return "checked";
    else return '';
}
```

But the result is that none of the radio buttons remain selected. I click to a button, the page reloads with the right results but the button does not get selected. Is there an easier way to do it??

Comment: insert the function call by `...".check($_session['PageNumber'], $val)."...` writing the code like this just inserts the word check(... into your string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concatenation is including your function name as a string so it will never fire. You need to move the function call out of the string

```
 $results .= "<INPUT........".check($_SESSION['PageNumber'],1)".; >1";
```